# Duplicate mark on question referring to newer one

Tags: discussion

[Coworker doesn't actually work - how to deal with the situation?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3840/coworker-doesnt-actually-work-how-to-deal-with-the-situation)  this question is marked as a duplicate of [What can I do to make a coworkers lack of effort more visible?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23165/what-can-i-do-to-make-a-coworkers-lack-of-effort-more-visible)

Why is a question which is about 1 1/2 years older than another one marked as a duplicate of the newer one?
Is there any guideline or reason behind this?

Comment: for a network wide guidance see [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/165773) at MSE: "If the new question is a better question or has better answers, then vote to close the old one as a duplicate of the new one..."

Answer (score 4):

> Why is a question which is about 1 1/2 years older than another one
>   marked as a duplicate of the newer one?

Because the older one was marked as a duplicate *after* the newer one was created.

> Is there any guideline or reason behind this?

Perhaps. But I'm sure the folks who marked it as a duplicate just thought that was a good idea.

@Lilienthal says that there is a guideline, which is just to use the duplicate marking optimally, which usually means to keep the most useful/general/viewed question as the parent. Age of the question has never been a criterion. – I don't know where that guideline is, a link would be nice.

Comment: The reason for it is to link the questions for indexing and search results.  Duplicate questions are never deleted.

Comment: "*Nope*" Well, there is a guideline, which is just to use the duplicate marking optimally, which usually means to keep the most useful/general/viewed question as the parent. Age of the question has never been a criterion.

Comment: @Lilienthal I agree that the better question should be the "prime" question with the others as duplicates regardless of date, but in this case the duplicate appears to have more higher-voted answers. I don't think it's an issue that needs to be fixed, but does seem odd to me.

Comment: @DavidK answer score doesn't reliably indicate quality ([The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/)). If you believe one of the questions / answers is better than another, this would better be discussed based on their content, not on score (and while we're at it, if some duplicate close direction goes too much against quality comparison it makes perfect sense to ask community or moderators do something to re-close in reverse direction)